# Question on variation of parameters method

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let's consider a non-homogenous linear ODE, say $y'(x)=A(x)y+b(x)$ where we are given some initial condition $y(\xi)=\eta$.

The standard way is to solve the homogenous ODE and then apply the method of variation of parameters to get a particular solution.

---

What happens if the solution of the homogenous ODE is the constant zero function? How do I get a particular solution in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is never just one unique solution to the homogeneous equation. Its *general* solution is
$$
h(x) = ke^{\int_c^xA(s)ds}\ ,
$$
where $\ k\ $ and $\ c\ $ can be can have any fixed values whatsoever.  While any solution of the homogeneous equation must be of this form, and  the constant zero function is always one of them— which you get by taking $\ k=0\ $—it is *just one* of them, and by no means the only one.

In the method of variation of parameters, you try to find a particular solution of the non-homogeneous equation by replacing the constant $\ k\ $ in the above equation with a function of $\ x\ $:
$$
y_p(x)=\varphi(x)e^{\int_c^xA(s)ds}\ ,
$$
and this is not at all affected by the fact that *one* of the solutions of the homogeneous equation is the constant zero function.